# Android Hetrogenenous recyclerview jerk and data model confusion

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a RecyclerView containing Horizontal RecyclerView and Vertical Recyclerview. I am confused about how to manage Data model for both. Here is my code followed by this [example](https://medium.com/@bipinAle/heteregenous-recyclerview-android-6d93b5ba3ff4)

```
public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final int VIEW_TYPE_DESIGN_TYPES = 0;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_DESIGNS = 1;

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Object> feeds;

    public HomeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Object> feeds) {
        this.context = context;
        this.feeds = feeds;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0)
            return VIEW_TYPE_DESIGN_TYPES;
        if (position == 1)
            return VIEW_TYPE_DESIGNS;
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view;
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;
        switch (viewType) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_DESIGN_TYPES:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_home_design_types, parent, false);
                holder = new DesignTypesViewHolder(view);
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_DESIGNS:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_home_designs, parent, false);
                holder = new DesignsViewHolder(view);
                break;
            default:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_home_designs, parent, false);
                holder = new DesignsViewHolder(view);
                break;
        }
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder.getItemViewType() == VIEW_TYPE_DESIGN_TYPES)
            designTypesView((DesignTypesViewHolder) holder);
        else if (holder.getItemViewType() == VIEW_TYPE_DESIGNS)
            designsView((DesignsViewHolder) holder);
    }


    private void designTypesView(DesignTypesViewHolder holder) {
        HomeAdapterDesignTypes homeAdapterDesignTypes = new HomeAdapterDesignTypes(getDesignTypes());
        holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(homeAdapterDesignTypes);
    }

    private void designsView(DesignsViewHolder holder) {
        HomeAdapterDesigns homeAdapterDesigns = new HomeAdapterDesigns(getDesigns());
        holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(homeAdapterDesigns);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return feeds.size();
    }

    public void updateFeeds(ArrayList<Object> mFeeds) {
        feeds.addAll(mFeeds);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class DesignTypesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        DesignTypesViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            recyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvHomeDesignTypes);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
            ItemOffsetDecoration itemDecoration = new ItemOffsetDecoration(context, R.dimen.item_offset);
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
        }
    }

    public class DesignsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        DesignsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            recyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvHomeDesigns);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 2));
            int spanCount = 2;
            int spacing = 15;
            boolean includeEdge = true;
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(spanCount, spacing, includeEdge));
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<DesignType> getDesignTypes() {
        ArrayList<DesignType> singleHorizontals = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < feeds.size(); i++) {
            Object object = feeds.get(i);
            if(object instanceof DesignType) {
                singleHorizontals.add((DesignType) object);
            }
        }
        return singleHorizontals;
    }

    private ArrayList<Design> getDesigns() {
        ArrayList<Design> singleVerticals = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < feeds.size(); i++) {
            Object object = feeds.get(i);
            if(object instanceof Design) {
                singleVerticals.add((Design) object);
            }
        }
        return singleVerticals;
    }
}
```

Now my Horizontal recyclerview is at position 0 and has static data items. Vertical RecyclerView is dynamic and I want to implement endless scroll for it. I dont know how to manage and update Data Model (POJO class) for both. Because Object type for both Recyclerviews are different. Should I create a common POJO class for both?

Another issue I am facing is that there is a jerk when list scrolls at the end.

Comment: You should create different POJO's for each of them. The `jerk` depends on the type of data and how you are loading it.

Comment: Don't you think that vertical scroll inside vertical scroll will cause smooth scrolling issue?

Comment: its not vertical scroll inside vertical scroll, its Horizontal RecyclerView inside Vertical Recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your parent recycler-view is designed to contain only two items:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0)
        return VIEW_TYPE_DESIGN_TYPES;
    if (position == 1)
        return VIEW_TYPE_DESIGNS;
    return -1;
}
```

But from here I can see that if you have more then two items - you will end up having all subsequent holders created as `DesignsViewHolder`:

```
default:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_home_designs, parent, false);
            holder = new DesignsViewHolder(view);
            break;
```

If the intent was - to have the top level recycler view with horizontal scroll and the next recycler view within grid items, then its pretty ok to have just two recycler views within one layout.

```
<ConstraintLayout or ScrollView> - as u wish
  <RecyclerView\> - horizontal one
  <RecyclerView\> - vertical one, or with grid layout manager
<\ConstraintLayout or ScrollView>
```

**EDIT**: On the attached to your question [link](https://medium.com/@bipinAle/heteregenous-recyclerview-android-6d93b5ba3ff4) we have a vice versa structure.
Vertical scroll and the last item with horizontal scroll. In such case u can switch the recycler-views ordering.

Still if you wanna have truly different items inside your recycler view its worth considering having the `Adapter Delegates` pattern.

**Pay attention**: having a lot of different scroll directions inside recycler view is not easy to maintain. Sometimes diff bugs occur, which are hardly fixable. In some cases it is easier to end up ***having a scroll view inside a recycler view***, ***instead of*** ***recycler view inside recycler-view***.
RecyclerView has a pretty complicated structure under the hood, which optimizes performance and items reusability. In most cases u need something simple with 5-10 items for horizontal scroll in terms of mixing this layout with vertical scroll.
A lot of things to discuss here, really case dependent.

Have a look at [Joe's problem](http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/adapter-delegates) and a nice [GitHub lib](https://github.com/sockeqwe/AdapterDelegates), those should help with Adapters Delegate pattern understanding. Good luck!

Comment: yes my requirement is to to show 10 horizontal items at top and then endless items in grid. So do you recommend to have two recyclerviews inside a scrollview?

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Comment: In that case Vertical Recyclerview's scroll wont work. ScrollView's scroll will work.

Comment: That was mentioned in mine answer, I have given an example of the layout. Also u can experiment with Coordinator layout and it's behavior.